# Does zero forms commute with wedge product for differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

Say $a,b$ are 1-forms, and $f$ is zero form, do we have $$fa\wedge b=a\wedge fb$$

I do not believe this is true as we have $$d(x\,dy\wedge dz)\neq d(dy\wedge x\,dz)$$ However, I just want to make sure this is the case.

Computation to show $d(x\,dy\wedge dz)\neq d(dy\wedge x\,dz)$:

Observe that $d(x\,dy\wedge dz)=d(x\,dy)\wedge dz+x\,dy\wedge d(dz)=(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)+0=dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$

On the other hand, we have $d(dy\wedge x\,dz)=d(dy)\wedge x\,dz+dy\wedge (d(x\,dz))=dy\wedge dx\wedge dz$.

The LHS and RHS does not equal as we need to change a sign when we swap $dy$ and $dx$.

***The zero forms should be passing through, I missed a negative sign when taking the derivative.***

Comment: Why do you think that the exterior derivatives are not equal? Please show your computation.

Comment: Added a computation, the two are not equal in terms of a sign.

Comment: The exterior derivative acts on wedge products by $d(\alpha\wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{\deg \alpha} \alpha \wedge d\beta$. You're missing a sign above.

Comment: Ayup. No problem with passing through a function ($0$-form) ...